# What is UISegmentedControl image size

Tags: ios

In my UISegmentedControl I wish to show icons instead of text.

I cannot find any indication what the height of these icons should be. I would prefer to supply properly sized icons instead of having the OS resize them for me.

So, when calling

```
[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[icon1, icon2]];
```

what should the sizes of these icons be?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the segmentControl a bigger frame.

```
UISegmentedControl *test = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[@icon1, @icon2]];

test.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 200, 80);

test.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.view addSubview:test];
```

itemsArray should be the items images array.